# Pre-Setup android field devices with apps and user accounts

Tags: android, remote-access

we are using android in the field for data collection, tracking etc. The phone is locked to only use some of the allowed apps. Most of the apps have a user profile assigned to it. We have over 100 devices.

Would it be possible to save user credentials on the phone? If this is possible we could push down a text file or similar with all the necessary user credentials for the apps.

Or is there some other solution to this? It's also a thing of setting up devices in a more effective way without having to sit with each phone and logging in manually once.

We had a look at 42 gears Sure MDM, mobilock etc. All devices are rooted, I am thinking ti should be possible to push down those login credentials and perhaps other settings too?

I guess we basically need to Pre-Setup the phones. Each with the correct apps and user details.

Comment: If the devices are rooted then you can install custom recovery image and then configure a zip file with all the apps which you need to preinstall. Use a updater script to install that zip on device boot.

Comment: Thank you. What about the user credentials?